# problemas con date() php

Tags: php, date

tengo un problema recurrente no solo en el proyecto que estoy desarrollando sino en varios.
Cuando utilizo la funcion date('Y-m-d h:s:m') de php, siempre me muestra una hora erronea y mas acercandonos a la noche, una fecha y hora erronea.

Por ejemplo, mientras escribo la fecha y hora es 2021-04-27 22:02:45 y la fecha del date es 2021-04-28 03:44:04. Tiene un error de aumentar 2 horas con 20 minutos a grozo modo.

No se si es un problema del lenguaje que interpreta algo mal o algo me falta.

Answer (score 1):

Primero de todo, el formato de fecha que estas intentando obtener es un poco raro.
Tienes lo siguiente:

```
date('Y-m-d h:s:m')
```

- Y - Año con 4 dígitos
- m - Representación numérica de un mes, con ceros iniciales
- d - Día del mes, 2 dígitos con ceros iniciales
- h - Formato de 12 horas de una hora con ceros iniciales
- s - Segundos con ceros iniciales
- m - Representación numérica de un mes, con ceros iniciales

Como ves, estás pasando donde los minutos segundos, y donde los segundos estás volviendo a pasar el mes.

Un formato 'normal' que puedes usar seria el siguiente

```
date('Y-m-d h:i:s')
```

Usando la s para mostrar los segundos en el sitio correcto y usando la i para mostrar los minutos.

- i - Minutos con ceros iniciales

Puedes ver los distintos valores aceptados en el formato de fecha en la [Documentación de Data()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php)

Esto deberia ayudarte con esos '20 minutos' que veias de diferencia.
Si sigues teniendo a parte las otras 2 horas de diferencia, lo más probable es que el servidor tenga configurada una hora distinta a la tuya.
Esto lo puedes arreglar definiendo el timezone en el servidor, o definiendolo en el propio php usando

```
date_default_timezone_set()
```

Aquí la [documentacion de date_default_timezone_set()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Esta función admite diferente tipos de zonas horarias como parámetros. Las puedes encontrar [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/timezones.php).

Como comentas que tu problema te pasa en más de un proyecto, lo suyo sería que encontrases la manera de configurar la hora correcta a nivel de servidor para no tener que ir proyecto por proyecto. Si usas algún panel de control tipo CPanel / Plesk, suele ser bastante facil el poder cambiar esta configuración.

Answer (score 0):

Hola tu problema es con el formato que estas usando, la "m" siempre será para meses con ceros iniciales, prueba con el siguiente formato:

```
date('Y-m-d h:i:s')
```

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Aparte del formato que estás usando, como bien dice @GerardoVite, la `m` significa la [representación numérica de un mes](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php), con ceros iniciales (`01` hasta `12`), debes tener en cuenta que **PHP trabaja del lado del servidor*+ y que cuando creas una fecha, la misma será creada en base a la zona horaria por defecto que tenga el servidor. Por tanto, si el servidor está en Australia y/o tiene por defecto la zona horaria de Australia, y tú estás en París, la fecha será en base a Australia, no a París.

Sea como sea, para trabajar con fechas te recomiendo que uses [la clase `DateTime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php), porque flexibiliza bastante el trabajo con fechas, para revisarlas, crearlas en base a una determinada zona, modificarlas, calcularlas, respresentarlas...

Por ejemplo:

```
$mDate=new DateTime();
var_dump($mDate);
```

Aquí el `var_dump` es para ver el objeto por dentro. Nos da esto:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2021-04-28 08:11:44.078444"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}
```

Aquí `$mDate` es un poderoso objeto, con el cual puedes hacer cualquier cosa, como imprimirlo con un determinado formato, hacer cálculos con él, cambiar su zona horaria, etc.

Por ejemplo, siempre sobre el mismo objeto:

```
echo $mDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');  //2021-04-28 08:11:44
echo $mDate->format('Y-m-d');        //2021-04-28
echo $mDate->format('W');            //17 (semana del año)
//Y así cualquier salida, siempre sobre el mismo objeto
```

Probemos a cambiar la zona horaria:

```
$mDate->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/Panama'));
var_dump($mDate);
```

Nuestro objeto ha pasado de Europa (Berlín) a América (Panamá):

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2021-04-28 01:21:56.074287"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(14) "America/Panama"
}
```

Puedes establecer una zona horaria específica también al crear el objeto, por ejemplo:

```
$mDate = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));
var_dump($mDate);

object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2021-04-28 18:25:50.959314"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Pacific/Nauru"
}
```

Puedes crear objetos partiendo de cadenas con un determinado formato con [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php), etc, etc, etc.

Puedes combinar objetos `DateTime` con [todas las otras clases que manejan objetos de tiempo en PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.datetime.php) para simplificar operaciones verdaderamente complejas.

Answer (score 0):

revisa que la zona horaria en el archivo de configuracion de PHP (PHP.ini) sea la correcta segun tu ubicacion geografica:

```
date.timezone = "US/Central"
```

https://www.php.net/manual/es/timezones.america.php

también revisa la zona horaria de la computadora que este corriendo tu aplicación